# Can we skip the keyclock login Page If we used the third-party directory server(like Azure) with angular?

Tags: angular, azure, authentication, single-sign-on, keycloak

I have setup the connection between keycloak ,microsoft and angular.

**The work flow is like:**

When i open localhost:4200 it redirects me to the keycloak login theme and there microsoft azure button is available and when i click on microsoft azure it redirects me to the login panel of microsoft azure , and after filling the credential i logged in successfuly to my angular application.

But i want instead of keycloak login theme …one input field will be available to enter the company domain(like xyz.com) and then redirect me to the microsoft azure login portal where i will enter the credential and will get successfully logged in to my angular application.

Answer (score 0):

*kc_idp_hint may be solve your requirement.*

when you redirect to keycloak url, you could

1. config thd kc_idp_hint param if you client support it
2. or you could manual appent the kc_idp_hint to your url.
   for example:

GET /youkeycloakhost.com?kc_idp_hint=facebook HTTP/1.1
replace the facebook with your config alias